# MS Word: Find/Replace multiple doc's at once

Tags: microsoft-word, search

I have about 50 document's in which I need to replace certain word's. Is there a way I can do this at once, not opening one by one. Also it would be very useful if I can use search option.
Thank's

Comment: Can be done via VBA or third party utilities.

Comment: thank's. i downloaded the program but still don't get it. please, consider that i am new in programming...

Comment: I didn't suggest any program, so what did you download?

Comment: you said VBA. this is Visual Basic for Application's, no?

Comment: Yes, but VBA is part of the Office programs like Word, Excel, PowerPoint. Visual Basic is a separate download, but VB != VBA. Also do keep in mind this site is not a code writing service, so you'll have to put in some effort first and show us how far you got.